# How to obtain an indefinite lock on database in Rails (postgres database) for QA purposes?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to obtain an indefinite lock on my Postgresql database (specifically on a table called orders) for QA purposes. In short, I want to know if certain locks on a table prevent or indefinitely block database migrations for adding columns (I think `ALTER TABLE` grabs an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK`).

My plan is to:

1. grab a table lock or a row lock on the orders table
2. run the migration to add a column (an ALTER TABLE statement that grabs an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK)
3. issue a read statement to see if (2) is blocked (the ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK blocks reads, and so this would be a problem that I'm trying to QA).

How would one do this? How do I grab a row lock on a table called orders via the Rails Console? How else could I do this?

Does my plan make sense?

**UPDATE**

It turns out open row-level transactions actually do block ALTER TABLE statements that grab an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK like table migrations that add columns. For example, when I run this code in one process:

```
 Order.first.with_lock do
    binding.pry
 end
```

It blocks my migration in another process to add a column to the orders table. That migration's ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK blocks all reads and select statements to the orders table, causing problems for end users.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're in a transaction, selecting rows from a table with various where clauses. Halfway through, some other transaction adds a column to that table. Now you are getting back more fields than you did previously. How is your application supposed to handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you getting at?

Comment: Also, it seems like after reading [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html) it seems like long-running SELECT statements (ACCESS SHARE lock) can block migrations that obtain an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock. Is that right?

Comment: Right. Reads and writes don't tend to block each other, but anything that alters tables etc tends to block / get blocked by things that change data.